# Multiple errors in deep reinforcement learning project with keras and openai gym

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have copied code from a source about deep q-learning to try to learn from it but it is an older source so there are many things that are going wrong with both keras and openai gym. I have tried for hours dealing with countless errors and as soon as I get through one another one comes up and I have no idea what is going on at this point. If anyone can take a look and help out it would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Create Environment
env_name = 'CartPole-v1'
env = gym.make(env_name)

num_observations = env.observation_space.shape[0]
num_actions = env.action_space.n

# Create Neural Network
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_shape=(4,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(num_actions))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

# Create Target Network
target_model = clone_model(model)

# Define Parameters
EPOCHS = 1000
BATCH_SIZE = 32
epsilon = 1.0
EPSILON_REDUCE = 0.995

LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
GAMMA = 0.95

def epsilon_greedy_action_selection(model, epsilon, observation):

    if np.random.random() > epsilon:
        prediction = model.predict(observation)
        action = np.argmax(prediction)
    else:
        action = np.random.randint(0, env.action_space.n) # Change the 9 later based on num of available actions in that state

    return action

replay_buffer = deque(maxlen=20000)
update_target_model = 10

def replay(replay_buffer, batch_size, model, target_model):

    if len(replay_buffer) < batch_size:
        return
    
    samples = random.sample(replay_buffer, batch_size)

    target_batch = []

    zipped_samples = list(zip(*samples))

    states, actions, rewards, new_states, terminateds, truncateds = zipped_samples

    targets = target_model.predict(np.array(states))

    q_values = model.predict(np.array(new_states))

    for i in range(batch_size):
        q_value = max(q_values[i][0])

        target = targets[i].copy()

        if terminateds[i] or truncateds[i]:
            target[0][actions[i]] = rewards[i]
        else:
            target[0][actions[i]] = rewards[i] + q_value * GAMMA

        target_batch.append(target)

    model.fit(np.array(states), np.array(target_batch), epochs=1, verbose=1)

def update_model_handler(epoch, update_target_model, model, target_model):

    if epoch > 0 and epoch % update_target_model == 0:
        target_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())

# Train the model
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=(Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)))

best_so_far = 0

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):

    observation = env.reset()[0]

    observation = np.asarray(observation)
    observation = observation.reshape([1, 4])
    terminated = False
    truncated = False

    points = 0

    while True:

        action = epsilon_greedy_action_selection(model, epsilon, observation)

        next_observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        next_observation = next_observation.reshape([1, 4])

        replay_buffer.append((observation, action, reward, next_observation, terminated, truncated))

        observation = next_observation
        points += 1

        replay(replay_buffer, BATCH_SIZE, model, target_model)
        if terminated == 1 or truncated == 1:
            break

    epsilon *= EPSILON_REDUCE

    update_model_handler(epoch, update_target_model, model, target_model)

    if points > best_so_far:
        best_so_far = points
    if epoch % 25 == 0:
        print(f"{epoch}: POINTS: {points} eps: {epsilon} BSF: {best_so_far}")
```

Currently the code is throwing the following error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4), found shape=(32, 1, 4). Although, there are many other errors that pop up other than that one.

Like I said I tried going through this for hours and I have made no progress in understanding what is wrong. I believe some things have changed in the versions of keras since the source I copied this from was made and that is causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The **ValueError** you have mentioned is version independent. To fix it, you'll need to reshape or cut your inputs to the specified shape, or specify a new shape.

Please refer to the below code for your reference.

```
input_layer= layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(2,2,1)) 
conv1 = layers.Conv2D(3,(2,2)) X= np.ones((2,2)) 
X =X.reshape(1,X.shape[0],X.shape[1],1) # shape of X is 4D, (1, 2, 2, 1)  
conv1(input_layer(X))
```

Please implement it in your code and it should work now.